# ¿Por qué las consultas no devuelven lo mismo?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, select

tengo una consulta sobre unas consultas select en oracle, estas son:

1)

```
  select sum(VA_PUNTOS_TOTALES) from CLPB_DOCUMENTO_MOV_ARTICULO where DA_FECHA_DOCUMENTO between '01/01/2017' and '31/12/2017';
```

2)

```
select sum(VA_PUNTOS_TOTALES) from CLPB_DOCUMENTO_MOV_ARTICULO where TO_CHAR(DA_FECHA_DOCUMENTO,'YYYY') = '2017';
```

el resultado de la primera es 14059720 y el de la segunda es 14076670,
entonces porque los resultados varían si la consultas prácticamente son iguales?

espero puedan resolverme la duda.
gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la respuesta aceptada hay un error que es necesario aclarar, el `BETWEEN` incluye los límites del intervalo, es decir `BETWEEN '20170101' AND '20171231'` incluye el año 2017 completo.

**Esto**:

```
SELECT FECHA,
       TO_DATE ('20170101','YYYYMMDD') DESDE,
       TO_DATE ('20171231','YYYYMMDD') HASTA
    FROM (SELECT TO_DATE('20170101','YYYYMMDD') AS FECHA FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT TO_DATE('20171231','YYYYMMDD') AS FECHA FROM DUAL) T
    WHERE FECHA BETWEEN TO_DATE ('20170101','YYYYMMDD') AND TO_DATE('20171231','YYYYMMDD')
```

**Sin duda, retorna esto**:

```
|                FECHA |                DESDE |                HASTA |
|----------------------|----------------------|----------------------|
| 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-12-31T00:00:00Z |
| 2017-12-31T00:00:00Z | 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-12-31T00:00:00Z |
```

Ahora bien, ¿dónde puede estar el problema?.. si tenemos campos de fecha y si además estas tienen una parte horaria, ahí puede estar el quid de la cuestión. Veamos un ejemplo:

```
SELECT FECHA,
       TO_DATE ('20170101','YYYYMMDD') DESDE,
       TO_DATE ('20171231','YYYYMMDD') HASTA
    FROM (SELECT TO_DATE('20170101 23:54:14','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') AS FECHA FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT TO_DATE('20171231 23:54:14','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') AS FECHA FROM DUAL) T
    WHERE FECHA BETWEEN TO_DATE ('20170101','YYYYMMDD') AND TO_DATE('20171231','YYYYMMDD')
```

**Resultado**:

```
|                FECHA |                DESDE |                HASTA |
|----------------------|----------------------|----------------------|
| 2017-01-01T23:54:14Z | 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-12-31T00:00:00Z |
```

Puedes notar que ahora los datos de fecha tienen hora, no tenemos problemas con la fecha desde ya que `2017-01-01T23:54:14Z` es mayor a `2017-01-01T00:00:00Z` sin embargo no ocurre lo mismo con la fecha hasta, `2017-12-31T00:00:00Z` es menor a `2017-12-31T23:54:14Z` a pesar que es el mismo día.

Como es un poco molesto tener que escribir la hora en los límites del `BETWEEN`, lo que puedes hacer es usar [`TRUNC()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2127.htm) para quitar la parte horaria de las fechas de la columna consultada:

```
    SELECT FECHA,
       TO_DATE ('20170101','YYYYMMDD') DESDE,
       TO_DATE ('20171231','YYYYMMDD') HASTA
    FROM (SELECT TO_DATE('20170101 23:54:14','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') AS FECHA FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT TO_DATE('20171231 23:54:14','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') AS FECHA FROM DUAL) T
    WHERE TRUNC(FECHA)  BETWEEN TO_DATE ('20170101','YYYYMMDD') AND TO_DATE('20171231','YYYYMMDD')
```

**Y ahora sí:**:

```
|                FECHA |                DESDE |                HASTA |
|----------------------|----------------------|----------------------|
| 2017-01-01T23:54:14Z | 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-12-31T00:00:00Z |
| 2017-12-31T23:54:14Z | 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-12-31T00:00:00Z |
```

Nota: Si usas `BETWEEN` no conviene hacer el truco de sumar un día al límite superior, ya que en caso de tener una fecha como está `2018-01-01T00:00:00Z` te la traería y no es lo que se busca. Si podrías usar esto si verificas los intervalos de forma independiente, es decir: `FECHA >= DESDE AND HASTA < FECHA + 1` (El `HASTA` se controla solo por menor)

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, tu respuesta sin duda nos ayudará a comprender mejor sobre el manejo de fechas, ahora me queda mas claro.

Answer (score 0):

anteriormente hice un proyecto que manejaba muchas funciones de fechas y trabajé específicamente y tenía que mantener uniformidad. Veo que tu problema radica en el cuál comparas una cadena de texto con un campo tipo fecha. El between no te toma en cuenta el 01/01/2017 sino a partir del 02/01/2017
al igual que no toma el 31/12/2017 sino hasta el 30/12/2017..

Estuve un tiempo con un problema similar, distinto al otro caso que si te mantiene. Si quieres hacer la prueba intenta colocar 31/12/2016 y 01/01/2019 y verás que tu resultado será idéntico al de la segunda función.

Espero te haya servido de algo. Saludos

Comment: En parte tenías razón ya que al convertir el texto a to_date cuadraban las cantidades, pero también funcionó de esta forma:

select sum(VA_PUNTOS_TOTALES) from CLPB_DOCUMENTO_MOV_ARTICULO where DA_FECHA_DOCUMENTO between '01/01/2017 12:00:00 am' and '31/12/2017 11:59:59 pm';

completando todo el formato de fecha y hora.

igual gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Ah listo, cierto, el formato predeterminado para fechas es con el time incluido. Me alegra que te haya servido mi respuesta. Saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 0):

Si uno no especifica la hora en una fecha, esa fecha es evaluada al principio del dia, es decir las 0 horas.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi' ;   

Session altered.

SQL> select to_date('31/03/2018','DD/MM/YYYY') from dual;

TO_DATE('31/03/2
----------------
31/03/2018 00:00
```

Ahora bien, el condicional *BETWEEN* toma un rango de fechas inclusivas, es decir, todo lo que se encuentre en ese rango. Col_A BETWEEN 1 AND 2 es igual a Col_A <=1 AND Col_A <= 2. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions012.htm#SQLRF52164

Asi que si tu pasas dos fechas sin hora, va a tomar el inicio de dia de ambas fechas. Ejemplo:

```
SQL> select to_date('31/12/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') - to_date('01/01/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') from dual;

TO_DATE('31/12/2017','DD/MM/YYYY')-TO_DATE('01/01/2017','DD/MM/YYYY')
---------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                  364
```

Como vemos aqui, el resultado nos da 364 dias en lugar de los 365 dias.

Sabiendo que el dia empieza a las 0 horas, y queremos obtener todos los resultados de ese dia hasta el ultimo (micro)segundo, entonces podemos poner con toda confianza el inicio del siguiente dia. Una transaccion que ocurra en el primer microsegundo del siguiente dia, sera contada en ese dia.

```
SQL> select to_date('1/1/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY') - to_date('01/01/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') from dual;

TO_DATE('1/1/2018','DD/MM/YYYY')-TO_DATE('01/01/2017','DD/MM/YYYY')
-------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                365
```

Esto funciona tambien con el between, nunca va a incluir la fecha del rango superior a menos que le agregues la hora:

```
SQL> select count(*) from calendar where first_day between '01/01/2017' and '1/1/2018';

  COUNT(*)
----------
        12
```

Espero les sirva.

AC